# hdrexposure program from SB OpenGL rendering blank screen

Tags: python, python-3.x, opengl

Relatively simple program drawing a blank screen. Ported from Superbible Opengl 7th ed.

The program is currently drawing a blank screen.  Although the textoverlay is working correctly.

Update: Added the use of `glGetError` to add additional error checking.  Though there is no error produced by it.  Still a blank screen however.

Update and SUCCESS: The program is now rendering the hdr image perfect.  Thanks to Rabbid76 excellent answer.  It was also a ktxloader that needed a fix.  Thank you.

Expected output is:

[image: expected output]

support files: [hdrexposure_support.zip](https://github.com/ohlogic/PythonOpenGLSuperBible7Glut/blob/master/chapt09/hdrexposure_support.zip)

ported from: [hdrexposure.cpp](https://github.com/openglsuperbible/sb7code/blob/master/src/hdrexposure/hdrexposure.cpp)

source code:

```
#!/usr/bin/python3

import sys
import time
import ctypes

fullscreen = True
sys.path.append("./shared")

from sbmloader import SBMObject    # location of sbm file format loader
from ktxloader import KTXObject    # location of ktx file format loader
from textoverlay import OVERLAY_
from shader import shader_load, link_from_shaders

from sbmath import m3dDegToRad, m3dRadToDeg, m3dTranslateMatrix44, m3dRotationMatrix44, \
    m3dMultiply, m3dOrtho, m3dPerspective, rotation_matrix, translate, m3dScaleMatrix44, \
    scale, m3dLookAt, normalize

try:
    from OpenGL.GLUT import *
    from OpenGL.GL import *
    from OpenGL.GLU import *
    from OpenGL.raw.GL.ARB.vertex_array_object import glGenVertexArrays, glBindVertexArray
except:
    print ('''
    ERROR: PyOpenGL not installed properly.
        ''')
    sys.exit()

import numpy as np
from math import cos, sin
import glm
identityMatrix = [1,0,0,0, 0,1,0,0, 0,0,1,0, 0,0,0,1]

myobject = SBMObject()
ktxobject = KTXObject()
overlay = OVERLAY_()

texture = GLuint(0)
program = GLuint(0)
vao = GLuint(0)
exposure=1.0

vs_source = '''
#version 420 core

void main(void)
{
    const vec4 vertices[] = vec4[](vec4(-1.0, -1.0, 0.5, 1.0),
                                   vec4( 1.0, -1.0, 0.5, 1.0),
                                   vec4(-1.0,  1.0, 0.5, 1.0),
                                   vec4( 1.0,  1.0, 0.5, 1.0));

    gl_Position = vertices[gl_VertexID];
}
'''

fs_source = '''
#version 430 core

uniform sampler2D s;

uniform float exposure;

out vec4 color;

void main(void)
{
    vec4 c = texture(s, gl_FragCoord.xy / vec2(512.0, 512.0));
    c.xyz = vec3(1.0) - exp(-c.xyz * exposure);
    color = c;
}
'''
def checkGLError():
    status = glGetError()
    if status != GL_NO_ERROR:
        raise RuntimeError('gl error %s' % (status,))

class Scene:

    def __init__(self, width, height):
        global overlay
        global texture
        global program
        global vao    

        self.width = width
        self.height = height

        overlay.init(80, 50)

        #// Generate a name for the texture
        glGenTextures(1, texture)

        #// Load texture from file
        texture = ktxobject.ktx_load("treelights_2k.ktx")

        #// Now bind it to the context using the GL_TEXTURE_2D binding point
        glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, texture)

        program = glCreateProgram()
        fs = glCreateShader(GL_FRAGMENT_SHADER)
        glShaderSource(fs, fs_source)
        glCompileShader(fs)

        if not glGetShaderiv(fs, GL_COMPILE_STATUS):
            print( 'compile error:' )
            print( glGetShaderInfoLog(fs) )

        vs = glCreateShader(GL_VERTEX_SHADER)
        glShaderSource(vs, vs_source)
        glCompileShader(vs)

        if not glGetShaderiv(vs, GL_COMPILE_STATUS):
            print( 'compile error:' )
            print( glGetShaderInfoLog(vs) )

        glAttachShader(program, vs)
        glAttachShader(program, fs)

        glLinkProgram(program)

        if not glGetProgramiv(program, GL_LINK_STATUS):
            print( 'link error:' )
            print( glGetProgramInfoLog(program) )

        glGenVertexArrays(1, vao)
        glBindVertexArray(vao)


    def display(self):
        global texture
        global program

        currentTime = time.time()

        green = [ 0.0, 0.25, 0.0, 1.0 ]
        glClearBufferfv(GL_COLOR, 0, green)

        glActiveTexture(GL_TEXTURE0)
        glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, texture)
        glUseProgram(program)
        glViewport(0, 0, self.width, self.height)
        glUniform1f(0, exposure)
        glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLE_STRIP, 0, 4)

        overlay.clear()
        buffer = ("Exposure = %2.2f (Numpad +/- to change)" % exposure)
        overlay.drawText(buffer, 0, 0)
        overlay.draw()

        checkGLError()

        glutSwapBuffers()

    def reshape(self, width, height):
        self.width = width
        self.height = height

    def keyboard(self, key, x, y ):
        global fullscreen
        global exposure

        print ('key:' , key)
        if key == b'\x1b': # ESC
            sys.exit()

        elif key == b'f' or key == b'F': #fullscreen toggle
            if (fullscreen == True):
                glutReshapeWindow(512, 512)
                glutPositionWindow(int((1360/2)-(512/2)), int((768/2)-(512/2)))
                fullscreen = False
            else:
                glutFullScreen()
                fullscreen = True
        elif key == b'+':
            exposure *= 1.1
        elif key == b'-':
            exposure /= 1.1

    def init(self):
        pass

    def timer(self, blah):
        glutPostRedisplay()
        glutTimerFunc( int(1/60), self.timer, 0)
        time.sleep(1/60.0)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    glutInit()
    glutInitDisplayMode(GLUT_RGBA | GLUT_DOUBLE | GLUT_DEPTH)
    glutInitWindowSize(512, 512)
    w1 = glutCreateWindow('OpenGL SuperBible - HDR Exposure')
    glutInitWindowPosition(int((1360/2)-(512/2)), int((768/2)-(512/2)))
    fullscreen = False
    #glutFullScreen()
    scene = Scene(512,512)
    glutReshapeFunc(scene.reshape)
    glutDisplayFunc(scene.display)
    glutKeyboardFunc(scene.keyboard)
    glutIdleFunc(scene.display)
    #glutTimerFunc( int(1/60), scene.timer, 0)
    scene.init()
    glutMainLoop()
```

Current output:

[image]

I was getting before updating the fragment shader:
[image]

Any help is appreciated.  Thank You.

Comment: Stan, it would be best if you stopped posting questions of the form "here's my code. It should do X. It's not doing X. Please figure out why it's not doing X for me". These are not very good questions, and they don't help you in any way improve your debugging skills. You're expected to do some debugging work on your own, and we would really prefer that you show what you've done to figure out where the problem is and is not.

Comment: I've received a lot of help from those who wish to help.  The program is not producing any errors so I don't know how to proceed as far as debugging at this point.  Though thanks for the response, I'll take it under advisement.  And ramp up the quality of any questions I have compared with the influx of daily questions.  I try and ask good questions, and as my code indicates I have made every effort to error check.  My efforts have been to port the entire program.  The cause is just and no one else seems to be doing it.

Comment: If you don't want to help, don't.  If my porting to python effort somehow disturbs you, please filter my questions from your inbox.  Have a good day.

Comment: "*as my code indicates I have made every effort to error check*" If I may ask... where is your error checking? I see no use of debug output for OpenGL errors. I see no use of `glGetError` for error checking (that may be part of pyopengl, I don't know). The only error checking you do is for your shader compilation/linking. Where is the rest? You presumably evolved this code from a working version that didn't render a texture. So which parts of your code changed from the working version, and which lines caused it to show a blank screen?

Comment: The relatively simple program is nearly identical to the working c++ version aside from the python syntax.  That's why I am stumped to why it is not working.  There are no lines of code I would deem as problematic at this point.  I appreciate you trying to help me, that I help myself.  But really,  I just don't know, and hence the question.   Thank you.

Comment: The use of `glGetError` may be a good idea.  Though the Superbible OpenGL authors themselves seem to disagree by not using the `glGetError` function at all in any of their examples.  I would be happy to add additional error checks whenever such a situation would be possible.  I'll have to look into using that function at all, more often. Thank you.

Comment: "*Though the Superbible OpenGL authors themselves seem to disagree by not using the glGetError function at all in any of their examples.*" OpenGL errors are user errors. If you have working, error-free OpenGL code, then you don't need to check for them. Since their code works, there's no reason to put error testing code in it.

Comment: @StanS. The value for the uniform `exposure` has to be != 0.0. Init exposure by 1.0 rather than 0.0. Note, in the c++ code it is initialized by 1.0, too.

Comment: Yes, that makes a big difference.  Now something renders on the screen, though not expected result.  Thank you very much for your insight.  I must have overlooked it when porting it over.  Thank you again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The result of [`exp(0.0)`](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/gl4/html/exp.xhtml) is 1.0, so the result of `1.0-exp(0.0)` is 0.0.
You've to ensure that the value of the uniform `exposure` is not 0.0, to get a result greater than 0.0 for the expression:

> ```c
> c.xyz = vec3(1.0) - exp(-c.xyz * exposure);
> ```

---

The texture data is of type `float`. Create [`numpy.array`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.array.html) with the element type `numpy.float32`, from the byte array, before initializing the texture image:

```py
for i in range(0, h.miplevels):

    if h.gltype == GL_FLOAT:

        float_data = np.frombuffer(data[ptr:], dtype=np.float32)
        glTexSubImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, i, 0, 0, width, height, h.glformat, h.gltype, float_data)

    else: # h.type == GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE

        glTexSubImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, i, 0, 0, width, height, h.glformat, h.gltype, data[ptr:])

    ptr += height * calculate_stride(h, width, 1)
```

Note, you've to implement different cases for different types.

Comment: Thank you very much.  I have updated the fragment shader source code.  Also added sample output as to what I'm getting.  Thank you.

Comment: @StanS. The issue is the initialization of the texture image (last part of the answer).

Comment: Excellent answer, thank you very much.  Works perfectly and great answer!